# issue with the reading binary data through stdin

Tags: c, linux

I am having problem with binary data while reading from stdin.

My application is having the delimiter as double newline as "2" when I enter two new lines it will stop reading through stdin and save the content into char buffer.
I am able to read the total bytes without missing till I press two enters, but the data where ever we are encountering the \n\r CR+LF it is modified as \n.

I am reading the windows based file teraterm and my hardware is Linux so I encounter this problem, in code level I have tried with

```
fgetc(stdin), getc(stdin)
freopen(stdin,"rb",1);
```

and

```
fread(buff,1,bufsize,stdin)
```

but no all the functions are reading and modifying the carriage return.
 So Please any one help me out from this problem.

Comment: on linux, fread(), getc() and so on does no translation of the input regardless of whether the file or stdin is in binary or text mode. If there is a \r\n, you will read both those characters, so your problem is something else. It's hard to guess what you're actually doing, but at a guess you're connecting something through teraterm, so the translation could be done by e.g. the telnet protocol, or a serial interface.

Comment: yes i am loading a file through teraterm using a serial interface,but i also cross checked with the driver which is doing the serial read,there is no such function i find that is translating the bytes it is just storing into a buffer.

Comment: Well, most terminal emulators certainly manipulate the data.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are reading binary data from a pipe. I recommend you to use the [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) system call instead, reading from the `STDIN_FILENO` file descriptor.

Comment: `freopen` either returns `NULL` or the older value of `stdin`, so is there any need to assign return value of `freopen` to `stdin`.

Comment: i also tried with read system cal but i am not able to give the buffer length because it is enter by user of any size ,i tried with read it is also not working...